# Error: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 1, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 4, 193, 229, 193] to have 1 channels, but got 4 channels instead

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

`RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 1, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 4, 193, 229, 193]` to have 1 channel, but got 4 channels instead.

Working on 3D Convolutional neural network for classification of Parkinson's disease.

I think this portion of the code has some mistake:

```
# Load the dataset using DataLoader
batch_size = 4

# Load the dataset with batch loading (adjust path as needed)
dataset = CustomDataset(root_dir=r'D:\PD\PD25_16bit', transform=ToTensor())
train_size = int(0.8 * len(dataset))
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [train_size, test_size])
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

# Define the 3D CNN model
class CNN3D(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_channels=1):
        super(CNN3D, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv3d(num_channels, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv3d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 48 * 57 * 48 // 4, 128)  # Adjust the linear layer input size
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 3)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, (64 * 48 * 57 * 48 // 4))  # Adjust the view to handle batch size of 4
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x
```

The dimension of each 3D file(NIFTI) is 193,229,193. When I changed the batch size the model consider it to be number of channel.

Answer (score 0):

The `Conv3d` function expects a 5 dimensional input of shape `(batch_size, channels, D, H, W)`. Your inputs have a single channel, so you need to add a unit dimension. Your input should be of shape `(batch_size, 1, 193, 229, 193)`